# how to model different json response from the same endpoint

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert the API data into dart model, but the problem is that the same endpoint/source returns the completely different JSON responses based on the which URL is passed in the parameter. How to tackle this issue?

For example:

```
// json response 1
{
 "title": "example",
 "thumbnail": "example",
 "url": "www.example.com",
 "urlList": []
}

//json response 2

{
 "title": "example",
 "thumb": "example",
 "video_url": "www.example.com",
 "videoUrlList": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about receiving all parameters?

In case of uncommon parameters like thumbnail, you can input empty string or set type nullable.

And then you can check response conditionally.

Below is example code block.

```dart
if (thumb?.isNotEmpty ?? false) {...}
```

Comment: the actual json response is very complicated, that was just for an example. Like one json response has only 7 keys and other one has more than 40 keys, both would be completely different

Comment: What I'm thinking do is create multiple dart models for each different json responses and after that, based on the parameter, the data would goes to their respective dart model, Is that correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you will have to create a service/function which processes the responses and maps to a single model (preferably) for your UI widgets to consume